# What is the walk around of moveTo method to keep moved cells with formulas unaffected

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem is that if any of the cells contain a formula, then after moveTo method formula does not update its references.

Below is the code I'm working on, it does the job except updating cell references.

```
//WORKING - MOVES VALUES FROM "A1:B.." TO "C+lastrow2"..
function my4() {
  var thiss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thissSh1 = thiss.getSheetByName("Entry");
  var lastrow1 = thissSh1.getLastRow()+1;
  var range = thissSh1.getRange("A1:A"+lastrow1).getValues();
  for(var i in range){
  source = thissSh1.getRange("A1:B1").offset(i, 0);
  dest = thissSh1.getRange("C"+lastrow1+":D"+lastrow1).offset(0, i*2);
  source.moveTo(dest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that format and values are copied. It doesn't mention formulas.

> [moveTo(target)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#moveTo%28Range%29):  Cut and paste (both format and values) from this range to the target range.

Obviously, it treats formulas like content - it would be nice if it updated them as if you'd moved the range by drag & drop in the spreadsheet.

There has been an open issue on this since 2011:

> [Issue 830](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=830): Moving a Range in a Spreadsheet should update formulas that reference it.

Star it to receive updates.

There are a couple of other issues with `moveTo()` worth noting:

> [Issue 138](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=138): Comments not moved or copied w r.moveTo or r.copyTo
>
> [Issue 464](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=464): Range.moveTo() does not handle overlapping source and destination ranges properly

#### Workaround

Use `getFormulas()` to retrieve the formulas from the original range, go through and transpose all of them, then use `setFormulas()` to put them in the new range.

Sounds simple, but isn't. In each formula, you'd need to identify cell references, determine if they were affected by the move, and change them if they are. Given the numerous ways that cells or ranges can be described, just identifying them would be tricky.

Error cases would need to be considered too: what about ranges that span the moved area? What if you end up creating circular references - those can cripple your spreadsheet.

You could create a typical double-looping function that would move & transpose a simple subset of formulas, I think. But for a general solution, I think we're waiting on google.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback! I came up with an idea of following workaround, which I don't know jet how to solve, since I started google-app-scripts just a few days ago.

**Possible Workaround**
1. Generate a unique range name for each cell that has to be moved.
2. Replace references in formulas with range names.
3. Move the first cell. References to other cells are maintained (I tested that). However, other cells will now refer to the previous location of the moved cell, so the name of old cell has to be deleted and the new location named instead.
4. Do the same with each cell in the range.

Do you think it would be feasible with google-app-scripts?

Best!